# TableViewCell Alignment Issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to Align the tableviewcell content like the below screenshot
[image]

but my alignment is like below only..
[image]

please any one help me to do..
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: and who should be ale to read that code?

Comment: What is the latest screen shot? Does it mean you have fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for top aligning of label text. Unfortunately there is no directly method for vertical alignment got UILabel.

```
//Code for top aligning text of UILabel
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(290, 35); 
        NSString *dateString =[[[reviewDic valueForKey:@"reviews"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"summary"];
        UIFont *dateFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        CGSize dateStringSize = [dateString sizeWithFont:dateFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:reviewLabel.lineBreakMode];

        CGRect dateFrame = CGRectMake(5, 17, 290, dateStringSize.height);

        reviewLabel.frame = dateFrame;
```

***reviewLabel will be repalced by your Label and you will have to make some adjustments according to your need.
Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, edit Autosizing of the bottom right label so the text is pushed to the top. This is in the Size Inspector tab